# fprintf inside a for loop is not working properly

Tags: c, for-loop, printf

I am attempting to create a text file using C that will contain a table of values in Fahrenheit and their Celsius conversion. 
I am able to use fprintf properly outside of the for loop but when I put it inside it does not print anything to the file. The code compiles properly but when I try to execute it completes but with exit code "-1073741819"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    FILE *filePointerThree;
    double myArray[100];

    filePointerThree = fopen("myFileFive.txt", "w");

    for(int i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = (i-32)/1.8;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<=100; j+=5)
    {
        fprintf(filePointerThree, "%d degrees F \t %5.2lf degrees C\n", j, myArray[j]);
    }
    fclose(filePointerThree);
}
```

Comment: You write out of bounds of the array, change to `i<100` and `j<100`. C arrays go from 0 to one less than the array size

Comment: If using an old compiler then putting `return 0;` at the end of main might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array needs to be larger to hold 101 values (0 through 100):

```c
    double myArray[101];
```

---

Upon further review, the code can be simplified to not require an array, as follows.  A `return 0;` at the end of `main()` will ensure an exit code of 0.  Minor: the `math.h` and `stdlib.h` includes are not required as `fopen()` and friends are defined in `stdio.h`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *filePointerThree;

    filePointerThree = fopen("myFileFive.txt", "w");

    for(int j=0; j<=100; j+=5)
    {
        fprintf(filePointerThree, "%d degrees F \t %5.2lf degrees C\n", j, (j-32)/1.8);
    }

    fclose(filePointerThree);

    return 0;
}
```